# Have a turtle follow a specific one from its neighbors

Tags: netlogo, multi-agent

I have turtles with 0 < AD < 1, and with 0 < opinion < 1. Each turtle is linked (undirected) to a given number of others. I want turtles low in AD (< 0.3) to adopt the opinion of another one high in AD (> 0.7) belonging to their neighborhood of links. The code I have figured out adopts all the opinions from all turtles with high AD within their extended network. Any thoughts on how to make this so that it *only* adopts the opinion of one in the neighborhood, *if there is one* (there may not be)?

This is related to a previous question ([Netlogo, changing link-with to link-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377614/netlogo-changing-link-with-to-link-to/54379194?noredirect=1#comment95646724_54379194))

```
to opinion-formation
ask turtles [ 
let leaders turtles with [AD > 0.7]
if (AD < 0.3) and (link-neighbor? one-of leaders) [set opinion1 [opinion] of turtles with [link-neighbor? one-of leaders ]]
]
end
```

Another thing I have tried, here the problem is that my turtles never adopt anyone's opinion...

```
to opinion-formation
ask turtles [
let leaders turtles with [AD > 0.7]
if (count leaders with [member? self link-neighbors] > 0) and AD < 0.3 [
set opinion1 [opinion] of one-of leaders with [member? self link-neighbors]
]
]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `nw` extension for this, as it allows you to use the `nw:turtles-in-radius X` primitive to return turtles within a connected distance. For a very simple example, have a look at this code:

```
extensions [ nw ]

turtles-own [ AD ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 10
  ask turtles [
    set AD random-float 1
    set color scale-color blue AD 0 1
    setxy random 20 - 10 random 20 - 10
    create-link-with one-of other turtles
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to check-leadership
  ask turtles [
    let my-nearby-turtles nw:turtles-in-radius 2
    let my-nearby-leader one-of my-nearby-turtles with [ AD > 0.7 ]
    if my-nearby-leader != nobody [
      let new-AD [AD] of my-nearby-leader
      show word "I have a leader, my new AD is " new-AD
      set AD new-AD      
      set color scale-color blue AD 0 1 
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Luke C. I had seen the nw extension in another model and hadn't yet given it a go. I have tested your suggestion in my code and it works perfectly, I finally get my turtles to update their opinion!

Comment: And I love the scale-color thing that is so helpful

Comment: @Pedro - No problem, glad you got it working! Cheers.